# Unit Test, Should you subclass the class you're testing?

Tags: unit-testing

I am starting TDD both at work and at home (I know I'm late to the party). I already have several tests for public methods for classes. However many of the classes I write have lots of protected functions. When creating a test class, should I have it subclass the class to be tested so I can have coverage on the protected methods?

Thanks,

Jec

Comment: Welcome to the party, everyone's invited! Could you elaborate a little on the purpose of the protected methods you want to test - are they there to expose functionality to sub-classes, or are they abstract methods/blank methods designed to be overridden by the sub-class?

Comment: Most of the protected methods expose functionality.

Comment: If a class has "lots of protected functions", then perhaps you should reconsider your design in the context of Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ideal world, you wouldn't need to test the protected methods directly, instead you would only be testing through the public interface. However, of course the world isn't ideal, and I don't think it's a bad thing to be testing protected methods if there is a good reason to.

I think whether to sub-class or not depends on the nature of the protected methods:

- If they are abstract or blank methods designed to be overridden by a sub-class, and you want to test that the methods are being called, then a testing sub-class is a good way to do this, as you can use the sub-class as a way to intercept these method calls and verify how they were called etc. One thing I would say is to be careful that any logic in a testing sub-class is purely for the purpose of verifying method calls, otherwise you could introduce behavior which may impact your tests negatively (for example, you could easily add logic to a testing sub-class which causes a given test to pass based only on the logic in your testing sub-class, and not the logic in the real implementation).
- If they are methods in a class designed to expose functionality to sub-classes, then I don't think that you need to sub-class the class under test. Because the methods are protected scope, different classes in the same package can access them, and therefore all you need to do is have your tests in the same package to call these methods to test them (which in my book is generally good practice, the tests should be in the same package but stored in a different directory).

Comment: Yea I wasn't really clear. The protected functions are mostly common code that most of the sub classes may need to use. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No problem, always a pleasure to respond to intelligent questions. Enjoy your foray into TDD.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome. It's never too late for the party!

Creating sub-classes to get access to private or protected methods is perhaps the best way. It creates the maximum "surface" for you to construct your tests.

In other situations, I have created sub-classes to allow me to instrument a class under test, to add factory and singleton patterns to a class under test, and to help allow substitutions of mock objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the class to test its protected interface.

Or you can let a mocking library do the subclassing. Depending on what the protected interface does, that may be preferable.

Specifically, if the base class uses the template method pattern, creating the subclass as a mock is probably better. If the base class just offers helper functions for the derived classes to use, consider putting them into a separate class and making them public.

Answer (score 1):

You should test public interface of your class.
So you don't need to write unit test for private or protected members.

Your private and protected members are called inside public members so when you test your public members all private and protected members will be tested implicitly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Many would argue that you should only test the public methods of a class.

Subclassing would work for protected properties and methods but would not work for private, internal, etc.

Depending on what language you use you can declare the test class and the class that it tests to be "friends" so the test class can see the other class' properties.